# Using grep for multiple patterns from multiple lines in a output file

Tags: linux, unix, grep

I have a data output something like this captured in a file.

- List item1

attrib1:  someval11

attrib2:  someval12

attrib3:  someval13

attrib4:  someval14

- List item2

attrib1:  someval21

attrib2:  someval12

attrib4:  someval24

attrib3:  someval23

- List item3

attrib1:  someval31

attrib2:  someval32

attrib3:  someval33

attrib4:  someval34

I want to extract attrib1, attrib3, attrib4 from the list of data only if "**attrib2 is someval12**".

note that attrib3 and attrib4 could be in any order after attrib2.

so far I tried to use grep with -A and -B option but I need to specify line number and that is sort of hardcoding which I don't want to do it.

grep -B 1 -A 1 -A 2 "attrib2:  someval12" | egrep -w "attrib1|attrib3|attrib4"

can i use any other option of grep which doesn't involve specifying the before and after occurence for this example?

Answer (score 0):

Grep and other tools (like join, sort, uniq) work on the principle "one record per line". It is therefore possible to use a 3-step pipe:

1. Convert each list item to a single line, using sed.
2. Do the filtering, using grep.
3. Convert back to the original format, using sed.

First you need to pick a character that is known not to occur in the input, and use it as separator character. For example, '|'.

Then, find the sed command for step 1, which transforms the input to the format

- List item1|attrib1: someval11|attrib2: someval12|attrib3: someval13|attrib4: someval14|
- List item2|attrib1: someval21|attrib2: someval12|attrib4: someval24|attrib3: someval23|
- List item3|attrib1: someval31|attrib2: someval32|attrib3: someval33|attrib4: someval34|

Now step 2 is easy.